# unity iventory. 1+1 = 4?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inventory

Hi so im trying to create an inventory system
but very strangely when i try and add 1 to the item amount of an item. it adds 3

so if  i add 1 item the next time i add one it will appear as 4 then 10 then 22 then 46 ect ect ect instead of just going 1,2,3,4

ive followed the variables im entering and at all stages they return the correct 1

its only after ive added it to the item amount it suddenly become the 4,10 ect`

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
         {
             Item test = new Item();
             test.ItemName = "testsss";
             test.ItemID = 55;
             test.Stackable = true;
             test.ItemAmount = 1;
             AddItem(test);
         }
 public void AddItem(Item item)
     {
         if (!isLocalPlayer) return;
         if (InventoryCurrentWeight + item.ItemWeight < InventoryMaxWeight)
         {
             if (item.Stackable == true)
             {
                 checkIfItemExists(item);
                 InvGui();
             }
             else
             {
                 addItemAtEmptySlot(item);
                 InvGui();
             }
         }
         else
         {
             Debug.Log("Too Much Weight");
         }
     }
 public void checkIfItemExists(Item item)
     {
         if (!isLocalPlayer) return;
         for (int i = 0; i < inventory.Count; i++)
         {
             if (inventory[i].ItemID == item.ItemID)
             {
                 Debug.Log(item.ItemAmount);
                 Debug.Log("Before" +inventory[i].ItemAmount);
                 inventory[i].ItemAmount = inventory[i].ItemAmount + item.ItemAmount;
                 //CaclutateWeight();
                 Debug.Log("After" + inventory[i].ItemAmount);
                 break;
             }
             else if (i == inventory.Count - 1)
             {
                 addItemAtEmptySlot(item);
             }
         }
     }
```

and this is my item class that holds the data `

```
using System.Collections;


    using System.Collections.Generic;
     using UnityEngine;
     [System.Serializable]
     public class Item
     {
         public string ItemName;
         public string ItemDescription;
         public float ItemWeight;
         public int ItemID;
         public int ItemAmount;
         public ItemType itemType;
         public string Sprite;
         public bool Stackable;

         public enum ItemType
         {
             Coin,
             Weapon,
             Armour,
             craftingMat,
             StatItem
         }

         public Item(string name,string desc, float weight, int id, int amount, ItemType type,bool stackable)
         {
             ItemName = name;
             ItemDescription = desc;
             ItemWeight = weight;
             ItemID = id;
             ItemAmount = amount;
             itemType = type;
             Stackable = stackable;
         }
         public Item()
         {

         }
     }`


    `
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have attached the 1st script multiple times ?

Comment: nope just on the player,

Comment: 4 , 10 , 22 , 46 - It looks like that after you add 1 then you (by mistake) multiplies amount by two somewhere. It should not be difficult to find and debug all places where you access `ItemAmount` (or even better, change `ItemAmount` to property, so the only place where it's value can change is getter/setter, where you can easily set breakpoints).

Comment: updated my item class with getter/setters but it still does the same thinghttps://gyazo.com/7770ff133bbc4573118957ea4b6f8382

Comment: found the culplrit. a function i had origiannlt dismissed as the cause was somehow casuing it to happen.